# data compression Http 1.1

Tags: ajax, apache, http, gwt, compression

Have a query regarding data compression in HTTP1.1. My apache compresses the HTML/CSS/JS files which get requested by the browser. But wht about the serialized data that gets passed on the wire as a part of GWT asynch/AJAX calls? Will that get compressed as well?

regards
-J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer Simon. I did a bit of TCP traffic catpturing etc and came to know an interesting fact. GWT, compresses the data (Just the JSON data) on its own if the browser sends a request with accept encoding for zip/.gzip files.

I have a large grid and I issued requests using Fiddler, once with the headers and once without them. With headers the data size was about 1/7th size than the case when there were no headers.

this has nothing to do with the apache mod deflate. My apache mod deflate takes care of zipping only js/ss/html files.

cheers
J

Answer (score 0):

Possibly. The browser and webserver negotiate compression (the browser states what it supports, the webserver replies accordingly), whether that works for a particular resource depends entirely on your local configuration.